# Cannot convert pointer to member function to type pointer to function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, non-static

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
struct A
{int(*Law)(int, double);
 A(int(*L)(int, double) = LawNULL) : Law(L) {}
 };

struct B : public A
{int funct(int, double) {return 1;}
 B() : A(funct) {}
};
```

The problem comes in the line

```
B() : Law(funct) {}
```

as i get the error

> error: invalid use of non-static member function 'int B::funct(int, double).

I've also tried to change the class B as following

```
struct B : public A
{int funct(int, double) {return 1;}
 B() : A(LawNULL) {Law = funct;}
};
```

but this produces the error

> cannot convert 'B::funct' from type 'int (B::)(int, double)' to type 'int (*)(int, double)'

Is there a way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Plain function pointer and pointer-to-member function are completely different beasts, having very little in common. `funct` can't be called on its own - being a non-static member, it requires an instance of `B` to be called on. Your question looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what are you ultimately trying to achieve? I suspect you might benefit from reading about [virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)

Comment: Pointer to functions are a very poor tool. They can't carry state and you shouldn't design interface around them.

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully? There is an invalid use of a *non-static* member function. What can you do to your member function to make that error message no longer applicable?